# How to fix loop return incremented value after terminated?

Tags: javascript

I want to execute this script 2 time and it was perfectly run 2 time but problem is that when in the end of the script when I alert ‘variable X’ it would return 3 instead of 2 and is value of "X" in second last statement

```
for(x=1; x <=2; x++){
      var prog = document.getElementById('progress'+x);
      var courseID = document.getElementById('c-id'+x).value;
      console.log(courseID);

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("get","../PhpFiles/sendProgress.php?r=returnP&course_id="+courseID,true);
      xhr.send();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){

      prog.innerText = xhr.responseText+'%';

        alert("after response:"+ x);
       move(xhr.responseText,x);


      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: looks like a `while` loop would be more suited here

Comment: Or a `.querySelector()` and `.forEach()`. Inside the for-loop, x has to be incremented to 3 before `x <= 2` is no longer true. So if it matters that x is 3 before the first server response even arrives, a for-loop is not appropriate.